# ASPNET_regiis - Failure to create exportable key set

Tags: asp.net, encryption, rsa, aspnet-regiis.exe

I'm trying to create an exportable key set using aspnet regiis, here is the command I'm running:

```
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319>aspnet_regiis -pc "SampleKeys" -exp
```

But the response is the same as if the tool is given a command it doesn't recognise:

```
Administration utility (4.0.30319) to install and uninstall ASP.NET on the local machine.
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
```

Followed by regular command-line help section

So I ommitted the -exp flag and just ran

```
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319>aspnet_regiis -pc "SampleKeys"
```

Which worked fine, but when I try to export the key using this command:

```
aspnet_regiis -px "SampleKeys" "C:\SampleKeys.xml" -pri
```

I get the following:

```
Exporting RSA Keys to file...
Key not valid for use in specified state.

Failed!
```

Has anyone had this problem before? I seemed to be able to do this without issue a few months ago. I've tried this on several machines and different .NET versions already and the same result is returned....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how but right after I posted this question I was able to create an exportable key set using the same command I used before:

```
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319>aspnet_regiis -pc "SampleKeys" -exp
```

Keys are importable on other machines and work as expected

Comment: The same thing happened to me. I executed the command from a different path to see it was because of rights, and it worked. I re launched it in the Framework folder and it worked. If someone has an explanation, I'll be glad to hear it.